# ndtrack prompt after macbook was upgraded from highsierra to mojave

Tags: mojave

What shall I do to address this ndtrack issue? I did some research online but didn't find anything particularly useful.
[image: ndtrack prompt]

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a feature of of Mojave. It recognizes that the software you have installed on your Mac "ndtrack" will not work if you upgrade your Mac to (currently in beta) macOS Catalina.

You should seek out an updated version of ndtrack before you upgrade to macOS Catalina.

If you have no current intention of upgrading to macOS Catalina (the final version will likely be released in the Fall) then you can just ignore this warning. But this should be updated before you do that upgrade as it will no longer work after the upgrade.

Other than that you can ignore the warning.

Comment: I didn't upgrade from Mojave to Catalina, but from HighSierra to Mojave.

Comment: Is `brew cask install ndtrack` good enough to update ndtrack? I didn't find anything online on how to update it.

Comment: Even have no idea on what `ndtrack` is.  :-(

Comment: I understand your upgrade path. I am just saying NDTRACK will stop working if you upgrade macOS to Catalina without updating ndtrack

Comment: Thanks, Steve. Sorry for my misunderstanding. By the way, do you know what I should do to upgrade `ndtrack`? So far I didn't find any guide on this.

Comment: Did you *get* it from homebrew?  No.  Cask is a truly evil thing, it hides where software actually comes from.  You'd want to read the formula, figure out where cask is actually getting it, then go THERE to see if it's been upgraded.